# bug with instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, instruments

So I was profiling my app using Leaks and Allocation tool in Instruments. I started off by switching to the call tree for allocations and then the option choosen was for created and still living. I have a UIScrollView that loads a bunch of images. So I went ahead and tried scrolling down to the UIScrollView. All my code is using lazy loading and only load images that are on the screen, didn't load all at once and it tries to reuse as much as possible.

When I do this, it seems like the amount of memory used I a particular method, in this example imageForText is always going up. from the start of recording to time X it goes from 0 MB to 5 MB. So I then switch the toggle to create and destroyed and then back to create and still living and I can see there the memory is just 2-3 MB now. If I don't do this switching it seems that it will only just go up linearly.

Am I just mis-reading or not understanding this? Is this a bug on Instrument in such that the created& still living is not reflected properly, such that you have to toggle back and forth to get the most recently accurate data?

Here's my graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Allocation Lifespan radio buttons: All Objects Created, Created and Still Living, and Created and Destroyed, affect the statistics for the Call Tree and Object List, which you can access from the jump bar. The radio buttons do not affect the graph's current bytes and the default statistics the Allocations instrument displays.

If you want to focus solely on active allocations, click the Info button next to the Allocations instrument. Select the Only track active allocations checkbox.